# rails convert object1 to object2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

i have a 2 obejct

name.to_json (object1):

```
[{"name":{"first":"1","second":"2"}},{"name":{"first":"11","second":"22"}}]
```

and object.to_json (object2):

```
[{"first":"1","second":"2"},{"first":"11","second":"22"}]
```

how to conver object1 to object2

```
rails 2

ruby 1.8.7
```

maybe I can use the map, but I have no ideas how to do it.

Comment: Those are not valid Ruby objects.

Comment: I recommend using RABL gem if u're working with JSONs. Take a look at it. https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Answer (score 0):

"Convert" meaning convert the structure ? I'll assume that your object1 is an Array of Hash (it is what it "looks like", but you are only giving the JSON representation, so I cannot be sure).

What about :

```
object1.map {|o| o["name"]}
```

In english : iterate on all objects in "object1", and return what the value behind the "name" key.

Complete example (copy/paste from a irb session) :

```
irb(main):003:0> object1 = [{"name"=>{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}}, {"name"=>{"first"=>"11", "second"=> "22"}}]
irb(main):004:0> object1.map {|o|o["name"]}
=> [{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}, {"first"=>"11", "second"=>"22"}]
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert the structure, but you solution not worked i see [null,null] when run object1.map{|o| o["name"]}.to_json

Comment: Just tried it in irb : irb(main):003:0> object1 = [{"name" => {"first" => "1","second" => "2"}},{"nam>
=> [{"name"=>{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}}, {"name"=>{"first"=>"11", "second"=>
"22"}}]
irb(main):004:0> object1.map {|o|o["name"]}
=> [{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}, {"first"=>"11", "second"=>"22"}]

Comment: What are the type of object1 & 2 ? You are only showing their JSON representation. I suppose those are Arrays of Hashes, but I am not sure, could you precise it ? My answer works in this cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want this

```
[1] pry(main)> require "json"
=> true
[2] pry(main)> JSON.parse('[{"name":{"first":"1","second":"2"}},{"name":{"first":"11","second":"22"}}]')
=> [{"name"=>{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}},
 {"name"=>{"first"=>"11", "second"=>"22"}}]
[3] pry(main)> x.collect {|w| w.values}
=> [[{"first"=>"1", "second"=>"2"}], [{"first"=>"11", "second"=>"22"}]]
```